# How to cast to Long in Spark Scala?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This seems to be a simple task, but I cannot figure out how to do it with Scala in Spark (not PySpark).
I have a DataFrame `df` with different columns. One of the columns has a type `String` that should be changed to `Long`. How can I do it?

If I execute this code, I get the compilation error `Cannot resolve symbol col`:

```
df.withColumn("timestamp", col("timestamp").cast(LongType))
```

Comment: You can also use `$` instead of col as `df.withColumn("timestamp", $"timestamp".cast(LongType))` before this make sure you import  `import spark.implicits._`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col` to use `col()` function.

Comment: You also need to import `org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType`